# How to assign a default value at runtime with Workflow Foundation WF4?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Using Windows Workflow Foundation WF4, I've got a custom activity with a `System.Guid` property called `UniqueId`.

I want the user to be able to drag my activity onto a workflow and have it automatically generate a new GUID value for `UniqueId`.

What's the easiest way to assign a new, read-only GUID value to this property at **design time**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use an [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx) and in the Create() build the activity with default properties as you want it. Then you add the IActivityTemplateFactory instead of the activity itself to the toolbox.

Comment: Dangit, that was my low-hanging fruit!  Also, what I usually do is implement IATF within my activity itself (`public class MyActivity : NativeActivity, IActivityTemplateFactory`).  You don't have to do any extra work to get it working in the designer as expected (activities show up in the toolbox, IATF called when dropped on the designer).

Comment: Smart. Now why didn't I think of that. I always create a new class just for the IATF.